# PRF based on the GGM construction

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-generator

What's the differences between the concepts “pseudorandom generator” and “pseudorandom number generator”?

In fact, I want to implement a pseudorandom function based on GGM's construction at http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/GGM_PRF, but I need to get a doubling length PRG first. I cannot find any effective way to do this.

Can anybody help me or give me *another way* to implement a pseudorandom function?

Comment: ooh, that is a problem meeting when I search pesudorandom generator on the Internet."PRF based on the GCN construction" may be more direct.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : $\:$ He may have _had_ GCM in the title, but he wasn't the one who _put_ that there. $\hspace{.41 in}$

Comment: Ah, OK, sheesh, sorry about that @杨应彬. But I guess we are where we want to be now :)

Comment: I found one definition of PRF in TLS protocol (see https://github.com/tlswg/tls13-spec/blob/master/draft-ietf-tls-tls13.md) based on HMAC {{RFC2104}}.Do you think that is suitable for implementing a PRF with the form in the definition here -> https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/prf.html

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't learned to edit mathematical stuffs.

Comment: If you're OK with a PRF with that construction I don't see why you couldn't use that particular one. Of course it would be wise to wait until TLS 1.3 is finalized but I guess you could be excused for being a bit impatient. Beats me why TLS defines its own PRF though.

Comment: PS it could be that you are just in need of a KBKDF. In that case you might want to take a look at NIST SP800-108 or HKDF.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Maarten. I just need to implement a dynamic search symmetric scheme which says it needs a PRF with the general form like that definition but it doesn't specify which kind of PRF. And that's just one small step to build that scheme, sigh.

Comment: "dynamic search symmetric scheme" $\: \mapsto \:$ ["dynamic searchable symmetric encryption"](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/530.pdf) $\;\;\;$ ? $\hspace{.81 in}$

Comment: You are right Ricky.

Answer (score 2):

A pseudorandom generator is far more specific.

A pseudorandom number generator can just be statistical and/or produce an

endless stream of output and/or take extra entropy as input while it's running.

[This RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) gives a way to implement [a pseudorandom function](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/hmac-new.html).

In fact, if you hadn't specified that you wanted a PRG to implement a PRF, then

I would've just suggested $\;\;\; x \: \mapsto \: \operatorname{HMAC}\hspace{.02 in}(x\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}0) \: || \hspace{.02 in} \operatorname{HMAC}\hspace{.02 in}(x\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}1) \;\;\;$ as the PRG.

Comment: Why HMAC and not simply a cryptographic hash function?